# CSS - Height 100% Is bigger than the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

So the issue is that i have header and page content, i want to give the header a set height of 150px and give all the remaining space of the container, so i set it to be 100%.
But when i do that, the container that contains header and page content increases it's height.

I don't want to use percentage for the header, and i want this to work on all sorts of screens (if possible).

Here's my code:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    max-width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;

}

.content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

i can also include jquery if needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use css3 [calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), here is working example

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    max-width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;

}

.content {

    height: calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

and you can [check](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) browser support, [JSBin Demo](https://jsbin.com/yatinapuze/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you know height percentage is a tricky thing in css.  Height looks to the parent container and on up until theres px or some tangible height measurment, then the % can be applied.  In your example i started looking for the height and saw max of 100px but min of 1000px.  I think thats a conflict.

Next, i'm thinking you dont know easily know the height of the screen, right? So you'll probably want to get this from jquery $(window).height()

then you set the height of the .content (minus 150px).
    var theHeight=$(window).height();
    $(".content").height(theHeight)